# Extract and use all values or outputs of searchResultSet for sending an emails

Tags: java

I have this code that searching in the DB and giving me a list of emails like this:

*******@gmail.com

*******@gmail.com

*******@gmail.com

After the searchResultSet I want to use these email Addresses to send an email to them so how I can read them one by one as string.

first class:

```
public UserDto getEmail() {

        Connection connection = null;

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        ResultSet searchResultSet = null;
        try {

            connection = getConnection();

            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "SELECT EMAIL FROM USER WHERE USER.U_SEQ IN ('1','650')");
            
            searchResultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            return getEmail(searchResultSet);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                preparedStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private UserDto getEmail(ResultSet searchResultSet) throws SQLException {
        List<UserDto > result = new ArrayList<UserDto >();

        UserDto userDto = null;

        while (searchResultSet.next()) {
            userDto = new UserDto ();

            userDto .setEmailAddress(searchResultSet.getString(1));
            result.add(userDto );
        }
        return result == null ? null : result.size() == 0 ? null : result.get(0);
    }
```

its working fine.

Second class which is the class that I have to call this searchResultSet to get the emails and use them one by one. Now its working fine but it read and send an email for only the first email or to the value that is in the first row or the searchResultSet. My question is how I can use these rows one by one.

in the second class:

```
Delegate Delegate = new Delegate();

           UserDto userDto = new UserDto();

           userDto = delegate.getEmail();

           String toEmail = userDto.getEmailAddress();

delegate.sendNotification("****", "****", toEmail, "", "",
                   "", body);
```

Here I have to go round to get the values of all rows because only it send for the first email which is the value of first row of the searching result.

Any help!!!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the email body is the same for all recipients and does not contain parameters, you should collect all recipient email-adresses as List/Array and use Bcc: header of email instead.

Comment: the return for the result set for email should be a list not a string object, then you can traverse using any loop and trigger the sending

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT EMAIL FROM USER WHERE USER.U_SEQ IN ('1','650')"
```

This will return you multiple emails, not just one. So you need to attach it to multiple UserDto objects. Not one.

```
         public List<UserDto> getEmail() {
    
            Connection connection = null;
    
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    
            ResultSet searchResultSet = null;
            try {
    
                connection = getConnection();
    
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
                        "SELECT EMAIL FROM USER WHERE USER.U_SEQ IN ('1','650')");
                
                searchResultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    
                return getEmail(searchResultSet);
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    preparedStatement.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
```

and

```
    private List<UserDto> getEmail(ResultSet searchResultSet) throws SQLException {
        List<UserDto> result = new ArrayList<UserDto >();

        UserDto userDto = null;
        int index = 1;
        while (searchResultSet.next()) {
            userDto = new UserDto();

            userDto .setEmailAddress(searchResultSet.getString(index));
            result.add(userDto);
            index++;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

then in delegate,

```
List<UserDto> users = delegate.getEmail();
```

loop through users get email and send email

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I try what you post, but still not working with me.

Comment: it show this error: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index. any help please.